# How to display div depending in CGridVIew in admin in Yii

Tags: php, yii

In the database, there is a column `is_starred` which value is either `0` or `1`. Depending on `0` or `1`, I want to display a div with class in the column of CGridView in admin. i.e. if the values is `0`, I want to display the div as `<div class="bookmark">☆</div>` or if the values is `1`, I want to display `<div class="bookmark active">☆</div>`. How can I do this could you me anybody please.

Comment: Which part of this is the challenge? (1) Getting the value from the database? (2) Making the value available to your view? (3) Using a conditional (or a ternary) to render different strings depending on the value?

Comment: I am getting the value. But do not understand how to display div and html class. depending or 0 or 1. I will not show 0 or 1 rather than the div and class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="bookmark <?php echo ($is_starred == 1) ? "active" : ""; ?>">☆</div>
```

This presumes that the database value is stored in a variable named `$is_starred`.

Comment: I tried as similar but it's giving me error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in C:\xampp\htdocs\contentbuilder\framework\base\CComponent.php(612) : eval()'d code on line 1`. Can you tell me it is happened. Thanks for your cooperating ..

Comment: However, I have done this, it was a syntax error and your answer helped me to get the concept. thank you.